# how to restrict user to uninstall application from android mobile

Tags: android

I want to develop an application which will not uninstall from mobile without authentication  if there is any solution regarding this feature please give me any solution.

Waiting for reply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to push your apk to /system/app.
To do that you need to root your device.

Just have a look: http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. If you could it would be a security breach.